# Get all methods from C# code using NRefactory

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, mono, nrefactory

How do I retrieve all the methods in a C# program using the NRefactory API ?

```
CSharpParser parser = new CSharpParser();
SyntaxTree tree = parser.Parse(code);
```

This creates a SyntaxTree but how do I get ONLY the list of methods from this SyntaxTree?

Answer (score 4):

There is an in depth [article about using NRefactory](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/408663/Using-NRefactory-for-analyzing-Csharp-code) available on CodeProject.

To get information from the SyntaxTree you can either visit the nodes or use the type system.

To visit the method declaration nodes you can do:

```
    var parser = new CSharpParser();
    SyntaxTree tree = parser.Parse(code);

    tree.AcceptVisitor(new MyVistor());

class MyVistor : DepthFirstAstVisitor
{
    public override void VisitMethodDeclaration(MethodDeclaration methodDeclaration)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(methodDeclaration.Name);
        base.VisitMethodDeclaration(methodDeclaration);
    }
}
```

To use the TypeSystem you can do:

```
    var parser = new CSharpParser();
    SyntaxTree tree = parser.Parse(code, "test.cs");

    CSharpUnresolvedFile file = tree.ToTypeSystem();
    foreach (IUnresolvedTypeDefinition type in file.TopLevelTypeDefinitions) {
        foreach (IUnresolvedMethod method in type.Methods) {
            Console.WriteLine(method.Name);
        }
    }
```