# NRefactory Find XML Doc Comments in Code

Tags: c#, nrefactory

I would like to get the xml documentation that is associated to a method using NRefactory. I got my feet wet by using the following code that I found in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25490149/1698964)

```
var parser = new CSharpParser();
SyntaxTree tree = parser.Parse(code, "test.cs");

CSharpUnresolvedFile file = tree.ToTypeSystem();
foreach (IUnresolvedTypeDefinition type in file.TopLevelTypeDefinitions) {
    foreach (IUnresolvedMethod method in type.Methods) {
        Console.WriteLine(method.Name);
    }
}
```

However, I was taking a look at the IUnresolvedTypeDefinition interface and it does not have any "Comments" property. Also, the IUnresolvedMethod interface does not have any "Comments" property. I do know that it is possible to retrieve the comments because I did so by using the WinForms application that is associated to the CodeProject article found [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/408663/Using-NRefactory-for-analyzing-Csharp-code)

The author of the demo does not use the "ToTypeSystem()" method. Instead, he traverses the tree. Below are some snippets of what he does:

```
SyntaxTree tree = parser.Parse(line, "demo.cs");

                    foreach (var element in tree.Children)
                    {
                        MakeTreeNode(element);
                    }


static void MakeTreeNode(AstNode node)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(GetNodeTitle(node));
        foreach (AstNode child in node.Children)
        {
            MakeTreeNode(child);
        }
    }

    static string GetNodeTitle(AstNode node)
    {
        StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
        b.Append(node.Role.ToString());
        b.Append(": ");
        b.Append(node.GetType().Name);
        bool hasProperties = false;
        foreach (PropertyInfo p in node.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance))
        {
            if (p.Name == "NodeType" || p.Name == "IsNull" || p.Name == "IsFrozen" || p.Name == "HasChildren")
                continue;
            if (p.PropertyType == typeof(string) || p.PropertyType.IsEnum || p.PropertyType == typeof(bool))
            {
                if (!hasProperties)
                {
                    hasProperties = true;
                    b.Append(" (");
                }
                else
                {
                    b.Append(", ");
                }
                b.Append(p.Name);
                b.Append(" = ");
                try
                {
                    object val = p.GetValue(node, null);
                    b.Append(val != null ? val.ToString() : "**null**");
                }
                catch (TargetInvocationException ex)
                {
                    b.Append("**" + ex.InnerException.GetType().Name + "**");
                }
            }
        }
        if (hasProperties)
            b.Append(")");
        return b.ToString() + "\n";
    }
```

I was wondering if there is a method in the NRefactory API that would get the documentation associated to a method in a C# piece of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did find a method that will get me the documentation associated to a method in the NRefactory API. It is the "GetDocumentation" method which has two overloads

- DocumentationComment GetDocumentation(IEntity entity);
- DocumentationComment GetDocumentation(IUnresolvedEntity entity, IEntity resolvedEntity);

Below is an example of usage

```
                SyntaxTree tree = parser.Parse(line, "demo.cs");

                var testClass = tree.Descendants.OfType<TypeDeclaration>().Single(x => x.Members == Method);
                var testClassAttributes = testClass.Attributes.SelectMany(x => x.Attributes).ToArray();

                List<Dictionary<string, object>> myList = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();

                string nombreControlador = null;
                string rutaControlador = null;
                string actionKeyPath = null;
                string fullControllerPath = null;
                int counter = 0;

                CSharpUnresolvedFile file = tree.ToTypeSystem();



                foreach (IUnresolvedTypeDefinition type in file.TopLevelTypeDefinitions)
                {
                    nombreControlador = type.Name;
                    actionKeyPath = type.Fields.Skip(1).FirstOrDefault().ConstantValue.ToString();
                    fullControllerPath = type.Fields.First().ConstantValue.ToString();
                    rutaControlador = type.FullName;
                    foreach (IUnresolvedMethod method in type.Methods)
                    {
                        string documentation = file.GetDocumentation(method).Trim();

                        XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse("<documentation>" + documentation + "</documentation>");        
                        Dictionary<string, object> myDic = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                        Console.WriteLine(method.Name);
                        myDic.Add("MethodSignature", method.Name);
                        myDic.Add("MethodDescription", doc.Descendants().Select(e => (string)e.Element("summary")).FirstOrDefault());
                        myDic.Add("ActionKeyPath", actionKeyPath == null? "" : actionKeyPath);
                        myDic.Add("Counter", ++counter);
                        myDic.Add("FullControllerPath", fullControllerPath == null? "" : fullControllerPath);
                        myDic.Add("Route", method.Attributes == null ? "" : method.Attributes.Count <= 1 || method.Attributes.Skip(1) == null? "" : method.Attributes.SelectMany(a => a.);
                        myDic.Add("Verb", "");
                        myDic.Add("Input", "");
                        myDic.Add("Output", "");
                        myList.Add(myDic);
                    }
                }
```

I am using the 5.0 version of NRefactorize by the way. I remember reading somewhere that the version 5.0 includes comments in the Abstract Syntax Tree